# Does my pineapple guava plant look ok?

Tags: guavas

I live in Southern California, Zone 10a, near Santa Barbara.  The summers here are mild and sometimes overcast, but temps can get into the 80s before cooling off in the fall.  There are established pineapple guava plants in our neighborhood, so I know they will survive here.  We planted one this spring and it hasn't done much in the way of growth.  I know these are supposed to be evergreen, but the leaves are browning.  The soil is somewhat loamy and I hand water it twice a week, about 2.0-2.5 gallons at a time.  Is this the right watering schedule and amount?  Should I be feeding it any kind of fertilizer?  Do I need to prune it?  Even though there are small shoots coming up from the ground, the plant itself isn't very bushy.  Any suggestions to help it thrive are welcomed.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Update: Most of the upper leaves have fallen off.  Newer, brighter yellowy green leaves are emerging below.  Not sure if this is normal or not?  If anyone has feedback, I'd greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.